# Are there any examples of diffusion PDEs with nonlinear complications, that would possess analytical solutions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

I need an example (at least one, but more are welcome) of nonlinear PDEs  in one space dimension (finite interval), containing transient diffusional terms plus some nonlinear complications, with Dirichlet boundary conditions, and initial conditions consistent with boundary conditions; the examples must possess closed form analytical solutions. I need the examples for testing the operation of some numerical code. If anybody knows such examples, I would appreciate an information.

Lesław